# Why was finding a hash beginning with a certain number of zeroes chosen as the proof of work?

Tags: hash, proof-of-work

It seems to me that the reason the proof-of-work involves finding a hash beginning with a (temporarily) fixed number of zeroes is because one can easily check whether they have solved the problem by comparing the hash they have generated with the value 2^k, where k = (256 - # of zero bits) and doing so is a relatively inexpensive operation. Also, it is easy to make the problem arbitrarily difficult up to a certain point (as well as having the difficulty increase exponentially with the number of zeros).

Are there any other reasons for why this particular problem was chosen for the proof-of-work?

Comment: It doesn't check for a number of zero bits. It checks whether the hash, when interpreted as a 256-bit number, is lower than a target number. That target number is occasionally adjusted.

Comment: Is the target number a power of two, or can it be any 256-bit number?

Comment: @Ali It can't be *any* 256 bit number (there's a format it needs to follow, [see here](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/how-to-calculate-new-bits-value)) but you can use very nearly any value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It reuses the [HashCash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash) construct invented by Adam Back (a scheme for proving work was done to send an email, resulting in it being treated as less spammy by spam filters), though with a newer hash function and different header structure.