# Would it work just fine if "bits" was set to "1cd86a52" instead of "1d00d86a" at the first difficulty adjustment?

Tags: mining-theory, difficulty, difficulty-retargetting

The first difficulty adjustment on the network happened at block `32256`. The time for block `32255` (one block before the adjustment) is `1262152739` and the time for block `30239` (2016 blocks before the adjustment is `1261130161`.

The `bits` for all blocks up until `32255` is `1d00ffff`, which gives the target `00000000FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. For reference, I arrived at it by doing the following:

```
% echo "ibase=16; 00FFFF" |bc
65535
% echo "ibase=16; 1D" |bc
29
% echo "ibase=10; 65535 * 2 ^ (8 * (29 - 3))" | bc
26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960
% echo "obase=16; 26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960" |bc
FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

After arriving at the current target, I multiplied it by `1022578` (time it took to mine the blocks from `30239` to `32255`) and then divided by `1209600` (2 weeks in seconds):

```
% echo "obase=16; 26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960 * 1022578 / 1209600" | bc
D86A528BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8BC8B
```

Now here is where things get confusing for me: from my understanding, the "bits" should be generated by picking up the first three significant bytes from the target, which would be `D86A52` and then add the size of the target as the prefix, which would be `1C` (`28` in base 10), but
when I retrieve the block `32256` using Bitcoin Core, I get `1d00d86a` for the `bits` field.

The difference between the targets would be pretty much irrelevant:

```
% echo "ibase=10; obase=16; 14182994 * 2 ^ (8 * (28 - 3))" | bc
D86A5200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
% echo "ibase=10; obase=16; 55402 * 2 ^ (8 * (29 - 3))" | bc
D86A0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I imagine these types of things happen because there's not a single source of truth for the target value of the network, meaning each node calculates the target independently and as such, these small differences can occur, but because the difference is so small the nodes would just have accepted it if I mined block `32256` using `1cd86a52` as the `bits`, but I don't know if this reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The consensus rules control *exactly* which difficulty a block needs to have (except on testnet3, where in certain circumstances a difficulty=1 block is allowed, in addition to the normally computed value).

In this case, `1cd86a52` is incorrect because it represents a negative number. The "compact format" used consists of 8 exponent bits, 1 sign bits, and 23 mantissa bits. The high bit of the `d` is the sign bit.

The rules require that the minimal exponent (which represents a power of 256, not of 2) is used for which the mantissa does not overflow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Okay, so I understand that `1cd86a52` is invalid because it represents a negative number, but then how do I get to `1d00d86a`?

Comment: I think I understand it by looking at https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/2926/139641. If I understood it correctly, because the first digit of the target I calculated is higher than `0x7f`, I should prepend a zero digit and then the compact form would be `1d00d86a`

Comment: It's the mantissa you end up with by picking the next higher exponent.